witt index or dim of maximally isotropic space for integral quadratic form
I am studying some problem related to  integral lattice with quadratic form $q(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb Z^n$. I know that a non-zero point $x$ is isotropic iff $q(x)=0$.
The space of such points form a isotropic subspace. I want to know the dimension of such space, or alternatively the number of linearly independent solutions to $q(x)=0$. From what I learned, this is called witt index.
In particular, I want to know the relation between witt inex and the signature of quadratic form. It seems that the witt index  $n$ satisfies $$ n\le min(r,s)$$ which are the signatures of quadratic form. Is this correct? How to prove it?

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406093/dimension-of-totally-isotropic-subspaces-for-a-given-quadratic-form

but what is the conclusion from that post? From the question, the conjecture seems to be n <= max(r,s) which is different from mine. From the answer, it seems to be n>=min(r,s)... what the conclusion? Also, I am considering integral lattice
